# About the determinant bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite cover of smooth curves, Consider a family $E$ of vector bundles over $X$ paramitrized by a scheme $T$,

> Is it true that the determinant of the cohomology bundles of $E$ and $p_*E$ are the same?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? They are bundles on different spaces.

Comment: The determinant bundle of $E$ is a line bundle over $T$; and the same thing for $\pi_*E$, they are both line bundles over $T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:X \times T \to T$ and $g: Y \times T \to T$ be the projections. Then $f = g \circ p$. It follows that
$$
R^if_*E \cong R^ig_*(p_*E),
$$
hence a fortiori
$$
\det(R^if_*E) \cong \det(R^ig_*(p_*E)).
$$